# Is this same colored-Bishop ending really drawn for Black?

Tags: analysis, endgame, bishop-endgame

I was playing as Black. Was there something I could of done to win in this position? Or was the game truly drawn? What are some endgame ideas for this position as Black? [image]

**Black to move**

Comment: I don't see any way for Black to make progress.

Comment: This is a dead draw.

Comment: Winning attempt: move `h5-h4`, then follow up with `Be6` and `Kd5-c4`.

Answer (score 3):

```
[FEN "4B3/8/7p/p1p1k1p1/P7/1bP1KP2/7P/8 b - - 0 1"]


1... Be6 2. Bb5 h5 3. Be8 h4 4. Bc6 Kd6 5. Bb5 Kd5 (5...Bd7?? {White has an attack now} 6. Bxd7 Kxd7 7. Kd3 { Targeting both e4 and c4} Kd6 8. Kc4 {Threathening with Kb5} Ke5 {Only thing to do is counter attack} 9. Kb5 Kf4 10. Kxa5 Kxf3 11. Kb5 g4 12. a5 g3 13. hxg3 hxg3 14. a6 g2 15. a7 g1=Q 16. a8=Q {With tempo, white will capture the last pawn of blacks, and keep his last pawn, mates in 42 according to Lomonosov tablebase}(8...Kc6?? 9. h3 { Black in zugzwang, White mates in less than 55 moves}) )6. Kd3 Ke5 7. Ke3
```

Black has fortress: All black pawns are in black squares, also the king in the center in a black square.

Potential White attacks: White has white bishop but there is no target. White king can try to sneak into blacks position via white squares but black can avoid this with his white-square bishop.

Verdict: White cannot progress.

White has a weaker fortress: White king occupies center with opposition, that's nice, but there are white-squared pawns which can be target for Black.

Potential Black attack: Black can target white-squared pawns by bishop, but these can be easily defended by bishop.

King can try to sneak but again, opponent bishop can successfully block it.

Also for any side, trying to sneak would result losing center and enemy can successfully counter-attack instead of preventing wing sneaks.

Thus we can say, any side who tries to sneak on wings using king, will lose center and will face a strong(probably winning) counter-attack from center.

Therefore the position is drawn.

Notes about edits: Edited the diagram to cover Dag Oskar Madsen's attacking idea.

Comment: You are probably right, but I'm not entirely convinced. Black winning attempt: move `h5-h4`, then follow up with `Be6` and `Kd5-c4`.

Comment: First of all, opponent bishop wouldn't let black to do Kd5-c4, please take a look, it's very hard to cover all lines. But I'm planning to give example continuations. Secondly h5-h4 achieves nothing, when black plays g4, pawn exchange happens white is freed up from one of his weaknesses, a pawn on white square. Now white has less weakness, easier to defend.